# how to map ports when deploying docker on AWS EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a service I want to deploy onto an environment in elastic beanstalk. If I want to build it locally I would use this line:

```
docker run --detach --name my-nlx-inway (some env en volume parameters) --publish 4443:8443 nlxio/inway:latest
```

I have tried setting all of this in a Dockerfile:

```
FROM nlxio/inway:latest
ENV NAME my-nlx-inway
EXPOSE 4443
```

When I deploy everything goes smoothly, my service is registered only it appears offline. I think it is in the mapping.
With the command I say `--publish 4443:8443` and in the Dockerfile I only say `EXPOSE 4443`.

So I tried building a `dockerrun.aws.json`

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1", 
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": 8443,
      "HostPort":4443
    }
  ]
}
```

I added the mapping with a configfile:

```
container_commands:
  00001_add_mapping:
    command: 'sed -i "s/docker run -d/docker run -p 4443:8443 -d/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh'
```

And I see the result in the logging:

```
'docker ps' ran at Tue Jun 11 12:20:02 UTC 2019: 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                NAMES
741a52caf467        f06676e20291        "/usr/local/bin/nlx-â€¦"   11 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       4443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4443->8443/tcp   optimistic_johnson
```

Comment: Are you sure tag **Ports** is correct?
Quick googling shows :

  `"portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80
        }`
portMappings
Maps network ports on the container to ports on the host.
====Update=====
https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/5qubwx/how_do_i_publish_docker_ports_on_elastic/
Maybe you also need to do some extra tweeking to make it working. Check post comment on reddis about elb, .ebextension settings

Comment: Portmappings is used with multicontainer and I use single. I will try tweeking the .ebextensions, that looks promising!

Comment: I think the tweeking worked correctly (meaning I can see what I changed but it's not yet registered) but I'm not sure about the '0.0.0.0:' part of the mapping. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

allright, besides adding the mapping with a configfile, I needed to add a listener. 
So my final structure looks like this:

```
- .ebextensions
  |-commands.config
- Dockerfile
```

And my `commands.config` looks like this:

```
container_commands:
  00001_add_mapping:
    command: 'sed -i "s/docker run -d/docker run -p 4443:8443 -d/" /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh'
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:4443:
    ListenerProtocol: TCP
    InstancePort: 4443
```